# JMS 2.0: DurableConsumer does not receive messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, jms

I'm rather new to programming in the Java EE environment, so this question will probably sound amateurish, but here goes:

I'm writing a simple JMS application for demonstration purposes. One of the features that has to be implemented is the ability to get messages from a topic after setting a message selector in a dynamic manner, menaing the user has to be able to set certain attributes that will determine whether he gets a message or not. The messages are sent from a different application that is running on the same local server as the application that is receiving the messages.

So, I'm using injected JMSContext components on both the sender side and on the receiver side to handle the messaging itself.

Here are the functions for sending

```
@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("jms/myConnectionFactory")
JMSContext context;

@Resource(lookup = "jms/myTopic")
private Topic topic;

//some more code

public void produceTopicForCreate(Object obj) {
    ObjectMessage message = contextCreate.createObjectMessage(obj);
    try {
        //setting properties
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        //logging
    }
   context.createProducer().send(topic, message)
}
```

And on the receiver side

```
@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("jms/myConnectionFactory")
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(lookup = "jms/myTopic")
private Topic topic

private JMSConsumer consumer;

private List<MyClass> listOfMessages;

//more code


public void subscribe(String selector) {
    this.consumer = this.context.createDurableConsumer(topic, "durableClient", selector, false);
}

public void receiveMessage() {
    try {
        this.listOfMessages.add(this.consumer.receiveBody(MyClass.class));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logging
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, I have created a durable consumer to consume messages from the topic. Now, whenever I try to invoke the receiveMessage method after a message has been sent to the topic, I get an exception, stating that the "Producer is closed". I looked all over the net, but found no indication as to what is the problem.

**If anyone here could help in any way, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!**

**Some important details:**

- the bean that is doing the sending is RequestScoped in app A
- the bean that is doing the receiving is a Singleton the implements
- the the environment is GlassFish 4.1/NetBeans 8.1